# Magento customer save memory leak

Tags: magento-1.7, model, memory, memory-leak

I'm trying to edit customer data in bulk (a couple of thousand records) and Magento keeps running out of available memory to run the script.

After some testing with `memory_get_usage()` the culprit seems to be the `$customer->save()` method which seems to take 5M of memory for each save but doesn't release it when done.

As a result, when looping through a couple of thousand records it is running of memory.

Here is what I've tried so far:

`$customer->clearInstance()`

`unset($customer)`

This doesn't seem to help though.

Below is my code:

```
public function createCustomerAddress($customerAddressData, $email){
     $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');

     $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
     $customer->loadByEmail($email);

     $address   = Mage::getModel('customer/address');

     $address->addData($customerAddressData);
     $customer->addAddress($address);
     unset($address);
     try{
         $customer->save();
     }catch (Exception $e){
         var_dump($customerAddressData);
         var_dump($e->getMessage());
     }
    echo "\n" . "Before unsetting \n" . memory_get_usage() . "\n";
    $customer->clearInstance();
    unset($customer);
    echo "\n" . "After  \n" . memory_get_usage() . "\n";  // no difference than before
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

p.s. I'm not sure if the `clearInstance()` function (in the Mage_Core_Model_Abstract) does anything, if someone has some insight into this it would be greatly appreciated if its shared :)

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?

Comment: Magento CE 1.7.0.2, but also testing it on Magento EE same issue

Comment: Instead of the workarounds provided as answers, it might be possible to track down the actual memory leak if you have time. Please see the two articles I provide. The first can help you track down the issue, the second explains a bug in PHP itself. It's possible that the same issue is present in Magento. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849549/diagnosing-memory-leaks-allowed-memory-size-of-bytes-exhausted

http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/262

Comment: what php version are you using?

Comment: @Flyingmana 5.4.17 on dev machine and 5.3 on production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is related to a core PHP issue, which is not easily resolved without extensive modifications to core Magento files.

The only way to get this done is using a workaround:

I propose:

a. If this is being called from the browser, I would do a separate ajax call, as @Julien Lacal recommended in his answer.

b. If this is all being done server side, I would break this down to two scripts, with 1. one that iterates over the existing customer list, and 2. one which calls the `createCustomerAddress` function, using post params. The second script should then be called using CURL from the first script, so that each instance of the second script runs in isolation, and is not affected by the memory leak.

Answer (score 5):

Memory is only released once there are no references to that variable/object. I suspect -- and will edit my answer once confirmed, that the event system in Magento passes an instance of the model to the observer, and therefore there is a reference to it in memory.

But this is a well documented issue. (one which I commented on in 2011 http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/26561/).

Comment: Definitely makes sense, however the observer should release it at some point

Comment: afaik does the standard php garbage collector NOT find circles, therefore it might be, that if you have a customer and an address, both objects are not freed - just an idea, thanks for the answer joseph!

Comment: Sounds plausible - at a quick glance only the newsletter module seems to observe the customer save event. @pzirkind do you see the same memory consumption with the newsletter extension fully disabled?

Comment: @Fooman yes it seems to have the same memory consumption when the newsletter module is disabled (via xml)

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a known issue across all platforms and versions of Magento. `unset()` or `clearInstance()` will not have any effect. `Mage::getModel()` leaked memory in all instances I've come across (customer, products, orders, etc.). The only way around that I have found is to use a collection instead, if possible (may not be applicable for you), when dealing with a large number of object creations. When your process is complete, the memory will be released.

Are you running out of memory? This is usually not an issue unless you are. If you are running out of memory, perhaps, you can try to break up the bulk process into separate runs in your extension. If this is in a shell script, then it would be easy to break it up. Just create two or more files and run them one after another with predefined ranges of customer `entity_id`s.

Comment: Thanks for the info will look into using collections for this, was wondering if there was some type of fix available for the model leak though

Comment: tried saving a collection using $collection->save() and seems to have the same memory leak, is there some code you can post where i could see the difference in memory?

Answer (score 2):

A good workaround would be to build your own admin module for bulk customer import, and have it use Ajax calls to a controller to import data in smaller sets. This way you won't run out of memory because it'll launch a new process each time you make that Ajax call instead of constantly allocating memory because of the `Mage::getModel('customer/address')`

Comment: That is an interesting workaround (+1 for the idea), but i want something more consistent for the backend

Answer (score 1):

Seems I found a major memory leak when calling `Model::save()`

After the item has been saved to the database there is the following code in the mentioned method:

```
$this->_getResource()->addCommitCallback(array($this, 'afterCommitCallback'))
```

This way the model gets added to the static parameter `$_commitCallbacks`. The method will be removed if the transaction level is set to zero only.

To solve this either add the following code to your own resource model:

```
public function addCommitCallback($callback)
{
    return $this;
    //return parent::addCommitCallback($callback);
}
```

This works only for one type of resource model, you need to do this to all resource models which are updated frequently in your loop. A drawback is that the method `afterCommitCallback()` of your model is never called.

Another (better) possibility is to overwrite the `commit()` and `rollback()` methods and remove the model from the variable in every case.